# Using multiple proxy generation hooks for creating a proxy

Tags: .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

Let's say I have a type like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual void InterceptedByA() { }

    public virtual void InterceptedByB() { }
}
```

I have two selectors named `InterceptorA` and `InterceptorB.` I want to use multiple `IProxyGenerationHook` implementations to ensure they only intercept their own methods. `ProxyGenerator` class accepts an array of interceptors but I can only use single `IProxyGenerationHook` instance in `ProxyGenerationOptions` constructor:

```
var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions(new ProxyGenerationHookForA());
```

Is there a way to use multiple `IProxyGenerationHook` implementations for creating a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

The IProxyGenerationHook is used at proxy-ing time only once for the object being proxy-ed. If you want fine-grained control about which interceptors are used for a method you should use the [IInterceptorSelector](http://kozmic.net/2009/02/14/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-v-interceptorselector-fine-grained-control/)

Here is a (very stupid) example that could help you see how you could use the `IInterceptorSelector` to match the methods called. Of course you wouldn't rely on the method names in order to match the selectors but this is left as an exercice

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pg = new ProxyGenerator();

        var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions();
        options.Selector = new Selector();
        var test = pg.CreateClassProxy<Foo>(options, new InterceptorA(), new InterceptorB());

        test.InterceptedByA();
        test.InterceptedByB();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public virtual void InterceptedByA() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
    public virtual void InterceptedByB() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}


public class Selector : IInterceptorSelector
{
    public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
    {
        return interceptors.Where(s => s.GetType().Name.Replace("or", "edBy") == method.Name).ToArray();
    }
}

public class InterceptorA : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InterceptorA");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
public class InterceptorB : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InterceptorB");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```